# Обработка doubleClick в заголовках и строках DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Требуется по разному обрабатывать `doubleClick` по заголовку и по строкам в `DataGrid`. `SelectedIndex` не подходит, так как при `doubleClick` по заголовку в `SelectedIndex` находится значение строки, которая была выделена ранее.

Как узнать, что клики были именно по заголовку?

Comment: Я точно не помню, но раз вы говорите про событие, то у события есть sender, можно поглядеть на него, или в самом событии поискать originalSource , по которому был выполнен клик

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете определить различные обработчики событий для строк и заголовков:

```
 <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
      </Style>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
           <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ColumnHeader_DoubleClick" />
      </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

в CodeBehind для заголовка

```
private void ColumnHeader_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var columnHeader = sender as DataGridColumnHeader;
     if (columnHeader != null)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```